# "Upload missing required dSYMs" while migrating fabric to firebase

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, crashlytics, google-fabric

I am migrating my ios app from fabric to firebase crashalytics and getting this error while working with crashalytics

**Upload 2 missing dSYMs required to process 12 crashes**

I already uploaded dSYMs file like this :
Organizer -> right click on build -> show in finder -> xarchives -> show package content and select dSYMs and zipped and uploaded to firebase
but still the same error occurs

Any suggessions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Download the dSYMs.zip file from Google Chrome.
If you download the dSYMs file from safari it will decompress the zip file and give you a dSYMs folder.
But we need the dSYMs.zip file which you will get by downloading the dSYMs.zip file from Google Chrome.

- Open AppStore Connect https://appstoreconnect.apple.com.
- Go to My Apps
- Select your app
- Click on the Activity tab from the top
- Expand/Select your version
- Find and click 'Download dSYM' button

it will download the zip file

Answer (score 1):

Probably, you need to upload dSYMs.zip. You can download it from app store. login apple developer account -> go to AppStore Connect -> select your app -> go to Activity tap -> Expand your version -> click your build link -> you can see dSYMs file. From here you can download it.

Comment: I downloaded from there and while I am compressing it I am getting this error
The file “Contents” couldn’t be opened because you don’t have permission to view it.

Comment: You don't need to compress it. Only you download zip file then upload it.